# Java change double to Date

Tags: java, date, double

There is a problem when I tried to transform double to Date.
This is my code:

```
double itemDouble = 1370437809.00;
long itemLong = (long) (itemDouble * 1000);
Date itemDate = new Date(itemLong);
String itemDateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS").format(itemDate);
```

When the `itemDouble` is `1370437809.00`, `itemDateStr` is `2013-06-05 21:10:09.00,`
but when the itemDouble's decimal places is not zero, such as `1370437809.66`, the `itemDateStr` is `2013-06-05 21:10:09.660`. The formatted date string is not right.

How this happened?

Comment: Why do you think that `2013-06-05 21:10:09.660` is not right?

Comment: If it's possible to change, don't use double to represent time. Not all numbers can be represented exactly with floating point numbers.

Comment: Side note: Consider to use the new Date & Time API instead of the legacy Date and SimpleDateFormat classes.

Comment: I sorry, my origin post had a mistake, the display is .SS, not .SSS. Please check my new post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your code, `1370437809.66` is a number of seconds since 1970. The decimal part represents 660 milliseconds. When you convert to a `Date`, you ask to display the milliseconds (the `.SSS` in the pattern). The result you get is correct.

Comment: I sorry, my origin post had a mistake, the display is .SS, not .SSS. Please check my new post.

Comment: The number of `S` does not change the reason. `S` means milliseconds. You have 660 milliseconds, so the formatter displays 660. The number of `S` controls the zero-padding of the value: with `SSS`, the value '5' will be displayed '005'; with `SS`, it will be displayed '05'.

Answer (score 0):

you have 0.66*1000=660 that's correct

Comment: I sorry, my origin post had a mistake, the display is .SS, not .SSS. Please check my new post.

Comment: hi, there was no critique. i can't comment posts yet, otherwise i would have done. i just wanted to say that there is no error.

Comment: Thank everyone for you help, this is the first time ask question here, I'v got the answer : )